# JavaScript play videos with same class control by play buttons with same class

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-video, selector

I'm trying to make 3 play/pause buttons for 3 videos. Each play/pause button controls the closest video.

```js
(function () {
    var play = document.querySelectorAll('.video_play_button'),
        video = document.querySelectorAll('.timeline_video');

    function videoPlay() {
        video.forEach(function (videoItem) {
            if (videoItem.paused) {
                videoItem.play();
            } else {
                videoItem.pause();
            }
        });
    }

    play.forEach(function (playItem) {
        playItem.addEventListener('click', videoPlay, false);
    })
})();
```

```html
<section>
<video class="timeline_video"></video>
<h3><span class="video_play_button"></span></h3>
</section>

<section>
<video class="timeline_video"></video>
<h3><span class="video_play_button"></span></h3>
</section>

<section>
<video class="timeline_video"></video>
<h3><span class="video_play_button"></span></h3>
</section>
```

When I hit the play button now, it will play all the videos. How do I make it only plays the closest video?

Thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean by closest video?

Comment: the video above play button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I hit the play button now, it will play all the videos. How do I
>   make it only plays the closest video?

You can use parentNode to get to `h3` and `previousElementSibling` to get to the `video` tag

You can modify `videoPlay` method to

```
function videoPlay( event ) 
{
    var videoItem = event.currentTarget.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
    videoItem.paused ? videoItem.play() : videoItem.pause();
}
```